# JavaScript Fullscreen API plugin

Tags: javascript, api, plugins

I've found a plugin called [screenfull.js](http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/) and I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically open the page in fullscreen without clicking on a button.
This is an example of code for making the page fullscreen :

```
document.getElementById('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
if ( screenfull ) {
    screenfull.request();
} else {
    // Ignore or do something else
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Using their demo, you could just run the request on window load:

e.g.

```
window.onload = function() {
    screenfull.request( $('#container')[0] );
};
```

**[edit]**
You could also run this with jQuery document ready...

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    screenfull.request( $('#container')[0] );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. The `requestFullScrenn()` must be triggered by a direct user action (like a click) for security considerations. It's just the same as with popups.

Read https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/Firefox10/CodeEditor/FullScreenAPI and maybe https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI for reference.

Comment: Thanks, but  I think it could be possible to trigger it  automatically after few seconds after the page is loaded ?

Comment: It should not, a automatically triggerd timeout is no user action.

Answer (score 1):

I use a trick...
        I listen for any click on the body to activate.
Eg:

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function() {
        screenfull.request();
    });
```

N.B.: It does not track buttons (e.t.c) that already have event handlers...